# permission_callback has no effect

Tags: rest-api, permissions, nonce

WP version is 5.5.3

I have 3 API routes set in a plugin that is used in an admin dashboard page. One route is meant to be used "publicly".

I have two very curious issues happening:

1. My 3 admin-centric routes do not specify `permission_callback`. I should be getting notices but I do not when the docs and WP core functions say it will throw a `doing_it_wrong` error.
2. My 4th public route does have `'permission_callback' => '__return_true'` set. I receive a `rest_not_logged_in` error code.

```php
class My_Plugin
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'rest_api_init', [ &$this, 'register_routes' ] );
    }
    
    public function register_routes(): void
    {
        register_rest_route('my-api-route', '/uri', [
            'methods' => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
            'callback' => [&$this, 'api_get_available_stuff'],
        ]);

        register_rest_route('my-api-route', "/uri/(?P<param>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)", [
            'methods' => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
            'callback' => [&$this, 'api_get_specific_stuff'],
        ]);

        register_rest_route('my-api-route', "/uri/(?P<param>[0-9-]+)", [
            'methods' => WP_REST_Server::EDITABLE,
            'callback' => [&$this, 'api_update_specific_stuff'],
        ]);

        register_rest_route('my-api-route', "/uri/(?P<param>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/load-more", [
            'methods' => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
            'callback' => [&$this, 'api_load_more_stuff'],
            'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
        ]);
    }
}
```

```js
// header approach
$.ajax({
  url: '/wp-json/my-api-route/uri/param/load-more',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'X-WP-Nonce': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce('wp_rest'); ?>'
  },
  data: {
    'max_items': 5,
    'offset': 5 * current_count,
  },
})

// _wpnonce approach
$.ajax({
  url: '/wp-json/my-api-route/uri/param/load-more',
  method: 'GET',
  data: {
    '_wpnonce': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce('wp_rest'); ?>',
    'max_items': 5,
    'offset': 5 * current_count,
  },
})
```

My only conclusion could be that, despite seeing "Version 5.5.3" in the bottom corner of WP Admin, I might not actually be on 5.5.3.

Comment: "I should be getting notices but I do not when the docs and WP core functions say it will throw a doing_it_wrong error." Where does it say that? If you don't have a permissions callback, the route will be public.

Comment: For reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#permissions-callback

Comment: 1. "functions say it will throw a doing_it_wrong error" - yes, but only if you [enable debugging, i.e. `WP_DEBUG` is `true`](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/). 2. "I receive a rest_not_logged_in error code" - maybe that's being returned from your `api_load_more_stuff()` function - check for `rest_not_logged_in` in your callbacks.

Comment: @SallyCJ load_more_stuff is running a query and returning the array. No other logic.

Comment: Heading in a different direction currently to where this issue becomes irrelevant. Still would like to know why this is happening but being frank, I don't care enough when needing to keep moving.

However, gonna keep checking back to see if others have thoughts.

Comment: @JamesWagoner, could be a plugin/theme issue - try deactivating all plugins and/or switching to a default theme, and see if the problem persists. Btw, I'm keen in knowing about that "different direction"?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that a `_doing_it_wrong` notice isn't being issued? You won't see the notice visibly output on the page because that would break the JSON response. But if you look in the headers of the response you should see a `X-WP-DoingItWrong` header.

It should also appear if you use a plugin like this to record developer notices: https://wordpress.org/plugins/log-deprecated-notices/

Comment: I did end up seeing a `X-WP-DoingItWrong` header but only in my dev instance. I also tail the error log during development and that is where I didn't see any logs when hitting endpoints that did not have `permission_callback` set.

Though, as stated above, heading in a different direction where this is not a problem for me anymore.

Comment: That **doing it wrong** did not write into debug.log file. It should do that. Up vote because I've never know it until see this answer. The error only appears when using new widget editor in WP 5.8.